# "restaurant" Parameter Not Accessed Pylance

Tags: python, numpy, pylance

Why does it give me a error saying the parameter "restaurant is not accessed Pylance?

[Restaurant Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkSM6.jpg)

My full code is below

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Unknown restaurant standard deviations
actual_restaurant1 = np.random.normal(loc = rand.randint(1,50), scale = rand.randint(1,10))
actual_restaurant2 = np.random.normal(loc = rand.randint(1,50), scale = rand.randint(1,10))

stand_dev1 = 100
stand_dev2 = 100
mean1 = 0
mean2 = 0
number_of_visits1 = 0
number_of_visits2 = 0

restaurant1 = np.random.normal(loc = mean1, scale = stand_dev1)
restaurant2 = np.random.normal(loc = mean2, scale = stand_dev2)

def update(restaurant, actual_restaurant, number_of_visits, stand_dev, mean):
    number_of_visits = number_of_visits + 1
    stand_dev = (1 / 10000 + number_of_visits) ** (-1)
    mean = actual_restaurant
    restaurant = np.random.normal(loc = mean, scale = stand_dev, size = 100000)

if restaurant1 > restaurant2:
    update(restaurant1, actual_restaurant1, number_of_visits1, stand_dev1, mean1)
elif restaurant2 > restaurant1:
    update(restaurant2, actual_restaurant2, number_of_visits2, stand_dev2, mean2)

plt.hist(restaurant1, 100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don’t use numpy so this might be wrong but i’m pretty sure your issue is that when you do “restaurant = …” it doesn’t actually do anything, so after you should do “return restaurant” and then when you call update just do “restaurant1/2 = update(…)”

Comment: Have you tried just running this in a command window (e.g. python restaurant.py)?  I ran your program from a terminal with the python command and it displayed a graph.

Comment: Why did you think that it should not give this error? The reason is that the "restaurant" parameter (of the "update" function) is not used.

Comment: @mkrieger What do you mean?

Comment: @NoDakker the problem is that the graph is of a single value whereas the graph should be of a standard deviation

Comment: @tygzy returning restaurant returns a single value when the function is used. I want the function to update the distribution of the restaurant

Answer (score 0):

It appears when your function is called, it appears that the function is receiving the list of values as the first parameter as opposed to a reference to the "restaurant" variable, which kind of seems counter to how functions are described for the python language.  Possibly because of the type of variable or object the restaurant statistical samples are, that's the way the function accepts the data.  I can't explain that.  Since that seems to be what is happening, the way I got the program to update your "restaurant1" or "restaurant2" objects was to set the function call up as an equation that receives a restaurant list back.  Then, the program generates the appropriate histogram.  Following is a revised version of your program.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Unknown restaurant standard deviations
actual_restaurant1 = np.random.normal(loc = rand.randint(1,50), scale = rand.randint(1,10))
actual_restaurant2 = np.random.normal(loc = rand.randint(1,50), scale = rand.randint(1,10))

stand_dev1 = 100
stand_dev2 = 100
mean1 = 0
mean2 = 0
number_of_visits1 = 0
number_of_visits2 = 0

restaurant1 = np.random.normal(loc = mean1, scale = stand_dev1)
restaurant2 = np.random.normal(loc = mean2, scale = stand_dev2)

def update(restaurant, actual_restaurant, number_of_visits, stand_dev, mean):
    number_of_visits = number_of_visits + 1
    stand_dev = (1 / 10000 + number_of_visits) ** (-1)
    mean = actual_restaurant
    restaurant = np.random.normal(loc = mean, scale = stand_dev, size = 100000)
    return restaurant  # This returns the value to be used in updating your restaurant variable.

if restaurant1 >= restaurant2:
    restaurant1 = update(restaurant1, actual_restaurant1, number_of_visits1, stand_dev1, mean1)
    plt.hist(restaurant1, 100)
    plt.title('Restaurant #1')
elif restaurant2 > restaurant1:
    restaurant2 = update(restaurant2, actual_restaurant2, number_of_visits2, stand_dev2, mean2)
    plt.hist(restaurant2, 100)
    plt.title('Restaurant #2')

plt.show()
```

When I ran the code, I did get a histogram with a fairly symmetrical bell curve look.

[image: Sample Histogram]

As I said, it seems like the function definition treats the restaurant variable like a constant set of data as if you were to call a function with constants.

```
average_value(24, 88, x)
```

Kind of a head scratcher.  Anyway, go ahead and experiment with that and see if it helps you out.

Regards.